# Loops and cursors in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Very Much New To Sql Loops & Cursors and desperately need a push here. Please Guide me in this.

```
With tbl as (
select empcode, refid
from tbltrans where date < getdate()
group by empcode, refid
)

select r.empcode, r.refid, sum(t.debit)debit, sum(t.credit)credit, 
(sum(t.credit)- sum(t.debit))balance
from ref r
left join tbltrans t on r.empcode = t.empcode and r.refid = t.refid
group by r.empcode, r.refid
```

The above query results as :

```
empcode    refid    debit   credit    balance    
----------------------------------------------
e1           r1      0        5         5
e1           r2      2        6         4
e2           r3      3        2         -1
```

now, I have to insert new records with related debit values to make the balance 0, which would be

```
empcode    refid    debit   credit  
-----------------------------------
e1           r1      5        0    
e1           r2      4        0    
e2           r3      -1       0
```

How should I do this. This is all i could make out.

```
DECLARE @empcode nvarchar(11) , @refid nvarchar(11)
DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR 
 //The above t-sql query here
OPEN c1 
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @empcode
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
 Insert into tbltransactions values(@empcode, @refid, @somevaluefordebit, 0)

FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @empcode
END CLOSE c1 
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use a **cursor** for this simple SQL???

Comment: Side note: Cursors are very slow and should not be used unless for a rather specific reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a cursor or a loop:

```
INSERT INTO tbltransactions(empcode, refid, debit, credit)
SELECT  empcode,
        refid,
        balance,
        0
FROM tbltransactions
```